# ui-grid how to select checkbox when row clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am showing data using`ui-grid.`

The `ui-grid` has three columns. The first column is contains `checkbox` for each row.

Data populating correctly, row selection works fine except the following issue.

**Problem:**

> When row clicked, the checkbox should also be selected. How i can achieve this? Any Idea?

**html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="datalist-uigrid testGrid">
            <div class="grid testGrid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

This is how i am defining my field.

```
{
    field: 'selected',
    displayName: '',
    type: 'boolean',
    cellTemplate: uiGridTemplates.cellTemplates.buildCheckboxEditCell('row.entity.IsOneOff', 'row.entity.selected', ' ng-change="grid.appScope.onSelectChange()"'),
    enableFiltering: false,
    enableSorting: false,
    width: '3%'
},
```

**gridOptions**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableCellEdit: false,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    enableGridMenu: false,
    rowHeight: 60,
    modifierKeysToMultiSelect: false,
    noUnselect: true,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```

This is how i am intercepting row click event

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
        $scope.onSelectRowChange(row.entity);
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;

    });
};
```

Comment: why not turn enableRowHeaderSelection: true in gridOptions, it will give you a checkbox by default

Answer (score 0):

By default the selection module provides a row header with checkboxes that allow selection of individual rows.
This can be done using `enableRowHeaderSelection: true`,

If you set the `enableRowHeaderSelection` in `gridOption` to false, then the row header is hidden and a click on the row will result in selection of that row.
If you want to allow both clicking on the row, and also clicking on the rowHeader, you can set `enableFullRowSelection` to true.

Please follow this tutorial for details:
[Row Selection](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection)

Answer (score 0):

```
<kendo-grid-column field="IsChecked" class="uk-text-center">
    <template  kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.IsChecked" (click)="SelectCheckbox()" (change)="dataItem.IsChecked = !dataItem.IsChecked" />
    </template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: please check [checked]="dataItem.IsChecked"